# SetInterval stops working when another tab opens and slows down the longer it takes

Tags: javascript, performance, tabs, setinterval

Good night,

I have a code that basically gets 5 random words from a list of 1500, converts them to base64 and base128, and then sends the result for a post after 1200 times.

Here I put the code that works good.

```
//variables
var pala = "";
var mystring = "";
var results = "";
var connt = 0;
var mystring2 = "";
var word = "";
var timeout2;

//function
function start() {
    timeout2 = setInterval(function() { //Run the script every 0.05 seconds

        connt++; //accumulator

        word = getwords(5); //get 5 random words separated by space from an array

        pala = ToCheck(word); //check words and return base64 of the words and base128 separated by space
        pala = pala.split(" "); //split

        mystring += pala[0] + '|' + word + '|' + pala[1] + ',\n'; //Create a string to be sent by post

        results = results + pala[1] + "|"; //create another string

        if (connt == 1200) { //When 1200 repetitions are reached (60 seconds)

            connt = 0; //reset accumulator
            mystring2 = mystring.slice(0, -2); //I delete the last line break

            $.post("php/metod.php?act=sent_word", {
                    message: mystring2,
                    results: results
                },
                function(respuesta) {}); //sent by post,This post searches the database and will compare. If it finds send an email and save it in the database.

            mystring = ""; //reset variable
            results = ""; //reset variable

        }
    }, 50);

}

$("#buttonx").click(function() {
    empezar();
});
```

But I have 2 problems:

**1. The code slows down while the user spends time running it. (Instead of sending a post every 60 seconds, 1200 laps for 0.05 seconds every lap, start sending them every minute, then every 4 minutes and so on).**

**2. When the user opens a new tab the code stops and when he returns to the tab the code stops working.**

Comment: If `empezar()` is supposed to be `start()`, then the problem is that you start a new interval timer each time the button is clicked. The old interval timers do not stop running.

Comment: Also, all of the timers will be incrementing the same counter `connt`, so the frequency of ajax requests will get higher and higher.

Comment: @Pointy , yes, sorry for my mistake, I speak Spanish so I put the word "empezar"

Answer (score 0):

String concatenation slows down execution as the string grows.  Instead, try using an array and then join the array with the join() function.  You might also want to remove mystring from the global scope.

Comment: Even if the string is restarted, does it slow down?

Comment: What you say is true, but I don't think that's the real problem here.